# MongoDB 3.2 authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, authorization

I create a user with the following set of commands. This should create user in both `admin` db as well as my target db (*c2d*):

```
# mongo 127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6-29-g5c19788
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show collections
system.users
system.version
> db.system.users.find()
> db.createUser({user:"cd2", pwd:"cd2", roles:[{role:"dbOwner", db: "c2d"}]})
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "cd2",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "c2d"
        }
    ]
}
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.cd2", "user" : "cd2", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "4g6t9kC+godz7k6QQOfD+A==", "storedKey" : "m3tDZBQDU2Tlb1lIjLGyTHmr2QQ=", "serverKey" : "GSA4OXSod1s8mBuZBtfmXq2tlTo=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "dbOwner", "db" : "c2d" } ] }
> use c2d
switched to db c2d
> db.createUser({user:"cd2", pwd:"cd2", roles:[{role:"dbOwner", db: "c2d"}]})
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "cd2",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "c2d"
        }
    ]
}
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.cd2", "user" : "cd2", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "4g6t9kC+godz7k6QQOfD+A==", "storedKey" : "m3tDZBQDU2Tlb1lIjLGyTHmr2QQ=", "serverKey" : "GSA4OXSod1s8mBuZBtfmXq2tlTo=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "dbOwner", "db" : "c2d" } ] }
{ "_id" : "c2d.cd2", "user" : "cd2", "db" : "c2d", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "vnMjnjfykVQS8ujQXeWaYw==", "storedKey" : "OYXivkmIwuTavlwTGfjrspT6j2E=", "serverKey" : "lw8xqzAaW8V4IQ9wOmQrG2VSp88=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "dbOwner", "db" : "c2d" } ] }
```

If I try to login, I'm welcomed with an error message:

```
# mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/c2d -u c2d -p c2d
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6-29-g5c19788
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/c2d
2016-05-22T10:35:41.862+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

Then I enable security features in the conf file and restart the server:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Error is still the same:

```
# mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/c2d -u c2d -p c2d
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6-29-g5c19788
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/c2d
2016-05-22T10:37:43.713+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Well, you'll need to take couple of steps in sequence to create user successfully.

First of all, you need to create an administrator user. I prefer creating super user.

```
> use admin
> db.createUser({user: "root", pwd: "123456", roles:["root"]})
```

Restart your MongoDB server and enable authentication with `--auth` flag.

```
> mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Once your server is up, connect to it as administrator

`> mongo <host:port> -u "root" -p "123456" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

Once you are connected, create normal user. Assuming your user database name is `cd2`.

```
> use cd2
> db.createUser({user: "cd2", pwd: "cd2", roles:["dbOwner"]})
```

If you see success messsage, disconnect from mongo shell and reconnect with new user
credentials.

```
> mongo <host:port>/cd2 -u "cd2" -p "cd2"
```

Comment: It is so lame when you find a good looking answer to your problem, but it doesn't solve it :-(. I am doing exactly this, with no success.

Comment: Well, it's unfortunate that this solution didn't worked for you. However, it does appear to be working for few other folks.

Comment: Yup... I can login via shell, but not via command line. Very weird. Don't worry though.. I didn't downvote this :-)

Comment: After creating users individually on each shard server, not dropping them, and restarting all components (mongos, configsvr, shardsvrs) several times, alternating between with `auth` and without, it seems the users are no longer present in any admin dbs. `db.system.users.find()` returns nothing, and attempting to authenticate as them gives the `DB.prototype._authOrThrow` mentioned in the question. Is this expected?

Comment: @WAF I don't think it's a normal behavior. Account should not disappear.

Comment: @WAF See my comment below. If you do it outside the DB host (remote shell), the accounts are transient. You close the shell session and they are gone. No idea why, but this is the behavior we can reproduce here.

Comment: One easy mistake to make is creating the user in the admin database instead of in the application database.  The "use cd2" portion of your answer helped figure this out.  +1 thanks.

Comment: Great answer! I had the same issue and logging out and back in as admin before creating a new user solved it. Can you please update the answer with steps to take form the mongo shell (>) vs terminal ($). It will make it much clearer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

If you log in through shell, make sure your create user under db "**admin**", **NOT** under a customized db. In your case you switched to "c2d".

Here is what I have tried (Log in as "admin")

#### 1. This one will work:

```sh
$ mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"
> use admin
> db.createUser(
  {
    user: "user007",
    pwd: "YourP@ssw0rd",
    roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "yourdb" },
    ]
  }
)
```

#### Output 1:

```sh
root@mongo-server:/# mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
MongoDB server version: 4.0.6
----
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "user007",
...     pwd: "YourP@ssw0rd",
...     roles: [
...        { role: "readWrite", db: "yourdb" },
...     ]
...   }
... )
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "user007",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "yourdb"
                }
        ]
}
```

```sh
root@mongo-server:/# mongo -u user007 -p YourP@ssw0rd

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("ceabf440-c584-4518-90f5-cc845eaec3b3") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.6
---
>
```

#### 2. This one will fail:

```sh
$ mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"
> use yourdb
> db.createUser(
  {
    user: "user007",
    pwd: "YourP@ssw0rd",
    roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "yourdb" },
    ]
  }
)
```

#### Output 2:

```sh
root@mongo-server:/# mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
MongoDB server version: 4.0.6
----
> use yourdb
switched to db yourdb
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "user007",
...     pwd: "YourP@ssw0rd",
...     roles: [
...        { role: "readWrite", db: "yourdb" },
...     ]
...   }
... )
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "user007",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "yourdb"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

```sh
root@mongo-server:/# mongo -u user007 -p YourP@ssw0rd
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-12-06T04:28:34.630+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: After 1-2 hours of trying to finding out why I couldn't login with user/password authentication this worked. The problem was that when I created the user, I was "using" my database instead of admin. For some reason, mongodb compass had no issue connecting however, only the cmd utilities gave me "Authentication failed".

Comment: Correction because it won't left me edit: Of course mongo compass was fine, it was using my db by default as authentication database

Answer (score 6):

Our experience with this issue on MongoDB (3.2.4) is that it seems a bug or a undocumented feature. 
If you attempt to create the users and roles from a remote shell (not localhost), the users are created but as soon as you leave the shell they are gone (they are transient to that session) and not really persisted.

**Solution:** Just try to create your users (without authentication enabled initially on MongoDB) and do it directly on the console of your DB server (localhost).

Comment: Hi, I have been facing a similar problem. Except, I have a shell script that does this on the console of my DB server, with the --noauth flag. But the same thing happens. The users are created but as soon as I leave the shell (or when the script finishes) they are gone! Do you have any idea why this happens? I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Hi again, never mind! I figured it out. My shell scripts were all terminating `mongod` with `kill -9`, which the MongoDB documentation says one should never do. (i.e. Never use **kill -9** (i.e. **SIGKILL**) to terminate a mongod instance). So I'm guessing i was terminating it unsafely, although I can't be sure, but I think changing that fixed problem. I use `kill -2` now

Answer (score 6):

try `--authenticationDatabase=admin` option in your terminal mongo command, if admin is the authentication database.

For example:

insteed of: `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/c2d -u c2d -p c2d`

use: `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/c2d -u c2d -p c2d --authenticationDatabase=admin`

Comment: I was having a similar problem to the OP and this one solved my problem - thanks