# Mongo Shell Is not Connecting when Using EBS volume for data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongo-shell

I am using `EBS volume` on my `EC2 instance` for storing data. And I installed and run mongodb successfully the only problem is that when I try to connect to `mongo shell` using `sudo mongo admin --username root --password MY_ec2LOG_PASSWORD` it give authentication error

```
root@ip-172-**-**-***:/home/bitnami# sudo mongo admin --username root --password MY_ec2LOG_PASSWORD
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017/admin
2016-10-05T09:19:34.710+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
root@ip-172-**-**-***:/home/bitnami#
```

but when I change the `dbpath` to EC2instance storage like normal folder and restart the mongodb and then run the same command it runs successfully.

I had already set the owner for the mount directory to the permission same as the other directory on which mongodb is working properly.

May I know why I cannot connect to mongo shell when using EBS as storage.

I am using Bitnami Mean AMI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed

Comment: how can I create a user if I am not able to enter the shell. and if I enter mongo shell without parameters and then when I try to run db.createUser() it again give me the authentication error.

Comment: Have you upgraded your mongo?