# how to get mongodb authentication right

Tags: mongodb

This has been driving me nuts ...

I had this working once, but it took me a day or two to get it right: A nice MongoDB database, with a bunch of collections, accessible through a Java client. All was good, except that I forgot to takes note on how I got this to work right.

Now I needed to add a second database. I could not get the authentication right at all - I added a new user to the admin db, no success. I added the user to the new db itself, still no success. I even tried the solution presented here: [MongoDB 3.2 authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed) ... but after that the entire mongoDB was locked, and all my data was lost. I had to uninstall MongoDB, and reinstall it from scratch.

Is there a simple step by step guideline how to set up a vanilla mongodb with a new database, and a user that can connect via Java (or any other remote client), using username/password? I googled for two hours now, but I have not found an answer yet.

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you setup mongodb, you should create a admin user with role userAdminAnyDatabase, and you will be able to create this user even mongod is started with --auth or not. you can create this user by below command.

```
use admin

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

After this if authorization is not turned on, on it by runnig mongod with --auth flag, or turn on authorization in mongod.conf and restart mongod server.

Then login to mongo shell  by below command with the admin user

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Go to the database, and create a user with readWrite permission.

```
use myapplication

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myTester",
    pwd: "xyz123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myapplication" }]
  }
)
```

Now you can use myTester user to read/write in myapplication database, and whenever you create a new database, start mongo shell with myUserAdmin user and create a new user for new database.

In mongodb you can also create a single user, and give him all permissions for all database, but that you should not do.

If you want to research further you can check below link. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/enable-authentication/

**And when you accidentally locked the mongodb, you can turn off the authorization  from mongod.conf file and access your data.**