# Start MongoDB in authentication mode in Ubuntu server

Tags: mongodb

We  have  installed MongoDB in AWS and it is running in without Authentication mode.  But we want to run MongoDB instance in authentication mode.  We have added the line  security:
                authorization: "enabled"   in  mongod.conf file . But  still  we are able to connect  our database without  any credentials.

Comment: Are you able to query from the db after connecting without credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to login because of localhost exception, you can login in DB to create users, as you haven't created any yet. As mentioned in mongodb site.

> You can create users either before or after enabling access control.
>   If you enable access control before creating any user, MongoDB
>   provides a localhost exception which allows you to create a user
>   administrator in the admin database. Once created, you must
>   authenticate as the user administrator to create additional users as
>   needed.

After it you should create Admin user with role userAdminAnyDatabase, and you will be able to create this user even mongod is started with --auth or not. you can create this user by below command.

```
use admin

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myAdmin",
    pwd: "123adc",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

And then create other users, for more detail you can go to another answer given by me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058794/3879440

Comment: Hi Puneet. What is the best way to start the MongoDB 3.0.3 in authentication mode in  ubuntu server.

Comment: The flow of enabling the authentication will be same as mentioned in answer, there can be syntax change. Check mongodb manual for more help - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: Thanks Punnet for quick reply....I have posted one question in below URL for  facing problem in starting mongodb in auth mode...     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339604/start-mongodb-3-0-3-version-in-authentication-mode-in-ubuntu-server

Comment: @pankaj I am not able to understand the question you gave link of, There can be small things go wrong while doing authentication.