# MongoDB IntelliJ plugin failed with auth

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

I'm trying to connect to my mongo instance wich I ran as `mongod --auth` after configuring

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

The configuration on Mongo-IntelliJ plugin looks like this:
[image]

The result is that the connection is refused.

Here is (some of) the output of **mongod**:

```
2016-10-26T08:40:09.218+0300 I NETWORK  [conn45] end connection 127.0.0.1:59014 (0 connections now open)
2016-10-26T08:40:09.718+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59015 #46 (1 connection now open)
2016-10-26T08:40:09.721+0300 I NETWORK  [conn46] end connection 127.0.0.1:59015 (0 connections now open)
2016-10-26T08:40:10.221+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59016 #47 (1 connection now open)
2016-10-26T08:40:10.224+0300 I NETWORK  [conn47] end connection 127.0.0.1:59016 (0 connections now open)
2016-10-26T08:40:10.725+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59017 #48 (1 connection now open)
2016-10-26T08:40:10.728+0300 I NETWORK  [conn48] end connection 127.0.0.1:59017 (0 connections now open)
```

I tried various combinations with the auth mechanism, but with the same results.

Is there something wrong in my configuration or in the plugin?

Comment: Are you able to connect via shell after enabling auth?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed

Comment: i have also connect mongo through intellij idea.. and its working fine.

Comment: I mange to connect by shell using:

mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"

Comment: @chirag did you connect with auth? because I can connect without auth, it is the auth that causing me problems

Comment: yeah m connecting with auth. and its seem similar as your