# Mongodb authentication error Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I am setting up mongodb for parse server.

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12

Here are following steps i use to setup mongodb.

```
mongo
> use mydbname
> db.createUser({ user: "mydbuser", pwd: "mydbpwd", roles: [ { role: "admin", db: "mydbname" } ] })
```

**Import db**

```
mongorestore ~/backup/mydbname --db=mydbname --username=mydbuser --password=mydbpwd
```

**Run NPM**

```
 npm install
 npm start
```

Till here it works absolutely fine.

But after some time or after 1 day it throws **Error: Authentication failed.** error

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: see if following post solve your authentication issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed