# Mongodb user permission read only issue

Tags: mongodb

I have an issue with permissions in Mongodb

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "tester",
...     pwd: "123456",
...     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
...              { role: "read", db: "TestHPO" } ]
...   }
... );
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "tester",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "test"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "TestHPO"
                }
        ]
}
> db.auth("tester", "123456" )
1
> use TestHPO
switched to db TestHPO
> db.createCollection("mycollection");
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

The test user has only read permission on TestHPO databases but can create and drop the collection in the above example.

This should be read-only which means just find, where is the issue with my code?

Comment: See my answer for another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using access control.

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control:

> Re-start the mongod instance with the --auth command line option or, if using a configuration file, the security.authorization setting.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Add Users - tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/)

Or

Another way.You should switch to database TestHPO and createUser again.

Answer (score 0):

Update/create config file for mongo db with below auth properties:
security:
   authorization: enabled
setParameter:
   authenticationMechanisms: MONGODB-CR

Restart the mongodb with --auth & --config:
mongod --auth --config C:\data\conf\mongod.conf

If the username or password contains a colon (:) or an at-sign (@) then it must be urlencoded otherwise throws exception.