# Mongo DB 3.2 Authentication

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I've just followed [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) on setting up Auth with Mongo DB, as well as [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed/37374366) to get a user set up as an administrator.

Running `mongo` > `use admin` > `show users` prints the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

After this, I run the server again with `--auth` and use the following command:

`mongo -u "root" -p "xxx" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

This prints the following:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: test
2018-03-29T15:52:32.329+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

Trying to run this without the `--auth` parameter lets me log in just fine.

The `--auth` parameter also gives me the following output in the server console:

```
I ACCESS   [conn1] note: no users configured in admin.system.users, allowing localhost access
```

But I'm actually unsure about why it isn't picking up any root/admin user I create. When trying to connect with Robo 3T, the terminal prints the following:

```
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx:44924 #2 (2 connections now open)
I ACCESS   [conn2] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on admin from client xxx ; UserNotFound: Could not find user root@admin
I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection xxx:44924 (1 connection now open
```

Comment: It's been a week since my previous comment, so I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

Issue fixed by following [this article](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/).

It seems that, despite using `--auth` when connecting to the server, by not commenting out the line `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` and adding `authorization: 'enabled'` to the `security` section in `/etc/mongod.conf`, I was only allowing access to the local machine - the server itself. The error messages could have been worded a bit better, but that's security. I guess.

Whilst this was a very silly oversight, no documentation I had previously looked at had covered this issue.