# Can't login to Mongo by shell

Tags: mongodb

We're working on remote MongoDB base through VPN. On my local machine are working three client instances: the NodeJS server, the Compass Community instance and the `mongo` shell (or `mongoexport`).

The same URL of the form `mongodb://user:pass@ip:port` is used in all three cases, and both the Node.js and the Compass work just fine. Problems begin to rise when I use the Windows PowerShell and call `mongo` from it:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://{ip}:{port}/
MongoDB server version: 3.6.4
2018-06-27T18:02:00.031+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

where `ip` and `port` are here placeholders for real values. We haven't got access to the Mongo config, so is there anything I can do to connect using the shell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed

Comment: Found the `--authenticationDatabase` key in the question on this link, after adding this I could connect. Seems that DB was just not configured to use `admin` database by default.

Answer (score 8):

It turned out to be possible to connect using explicitly stated authentication database. I.e., the following lines does work:

```
mongo --host mongodb://user:pass@ip:port/ --authenticationDatabase admin
mongoexport --host mongodb://user:pass@ip:port/ --authenticationDatabase admin --db db --collection collection -o ./file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you are using wrong database. After running `mongo` to start mongo, you have to use `use database_name` and then you can use `db.auth("username","password")` to authenticate.

**EDIT**

By default you database is admin, so you have to switch it up if you are using another database

Comment: I can't even `use` anything at all. I'm stopped by the said error just after the `mongo` command.