# I cannot login to mongodb after adding admin user and enabling authentication with ansible

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I want to secure my mongo db and I am attempting to do that with ansible and the stackoverflow answer to this question: [MongoDB 3.2 authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed)
I am using mongo v4.0.9. This is the relevant part of my playbook:

```
- name: Add mongo admin user
  mongodb_user:
    database: admin
    name: creds['mongo_admin_stg']['user']
    password: creds['mongo_admin_stg']['pass']
    state: present
    roles: root
```

When I run my playbook there are no errors.  Then I add the lines ...

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

... to my `/etc/mongod.conf`.

I am running mongod on a CentOS7 server so I then I restart the mongo service like so:

```
systemctl restart mongod.service
```

Then I attempt to get a mongo shell like so:

```
mongo tool-001:27017 -uadmin -pThePasW0ord  --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

But I get this error message:

```
2019-05-13T20:54:31.864+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
```

Update: If I open a mongo shell after I run my playbook and before I restart the mongod service I see that there are no collections in the `admin` database:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show collections
>
```

What am I missing here?

Update: Based on Zeitounator's answer.  I decided to just hard code the username and password and see if the `admin` user would get created.  SO I changed my playbook to this:

```
- name: Add mongo admin user
  mongodb_user:
    database: "admin"
    # name: "{{ creds['mongo_admin_stg']['user'] }}"
    # password: "{{ creds['mongo_admin_stg']['pass'] }}"
    # name: "{{ creds.mongo_admin_stg.user }}"
    # password: "{{ creds.mongo_admin_stg.pass }}"
    name: admin
    password: password
    state: present
    roles: root
```

And I run my playbook and it completes without error, but still if I open a mongo shell before updating my `/etc/mongod.conf` and before restarting the `mongod` server I still see no collections in the `admin` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess from your question you have declared a var earlier in your playbook:

```
creds:
  mongo_admin_stg:
    user: admin
    password: ThePasW0ord
  mongo_admin_prod:
    user: god
    password: S3cr3tHeaven
  #...#
```

(Side note: if this is literally what you did, have a look at [ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) and consider encrypting sensitive data)

You simply have a [jinja2 templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) problem (i.e. you are not using it): you are literally declaring the name of the variable you want to use (as a basic [yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) scalar) rather than replacing it by its value.

This is the correct syntax:

```
- name: Add mongo admin user
  mongodb_user:
    database: admin
    name: "{{ creds['mongo_admin_stg']['user'] }}"
    password: "{{ creds['mongo_admin_stg']['pass'] }}"
    state: present
    roles: root
```

Note that you can use the dot notation which is equivalent an probably more readable in this case

```
    name: "{{ creds.mongo_admin_stg.user }}"
    password: "{{ creds.mongo_admin_stg.pass }}"
```

**EDIT:** The above is fixed and was surely a blocker, but you are still stuck. My mongo knowledge is nill. Still, here is what I did and succeeded with.

1. I fired-up a mongodb docker container on my machine

```
docker run -d --rm -p 27017:27017 --name testmongo mongo:latest
```

2. I ran the above ansible task from my localhost (which targeted the open port in the container). This was a success.
3. I logued in the container, launched the mongo shell, selected the admin db... and issued a help... where I noticed there was a `show users` command available. This returns the new created user

```
> show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.admin",
    "userId" : UUID("2a379e96-d03b-47c2-bffa-82dccf566868"),
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

I just tried again on a freshly created container and the user is not there. So I'm sure the ansible task is creating it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `admin` user is still not getting created.  Please see my update.

Comment: I was able to complete your steps on a docker container with success... Edit coming. (Note: if you divide any number by my mongo knowledge, you get a runtime error :))

Comment: ah `show users` for some reason I thought there would be collections created in the `admin` database.  Now I got a bunch weird admin users I have to clean up :)